# How to find annotation usage using Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

Using Eclipse IDE, I'd like to get a list of all "things" annotated with a specific Java annotation.

For instance, I would like to get a list of all methods annotated with @Bean in Spring Framework's source code or JARs.

I'm aware that it's possible to look up annotation usage programmatically, as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package). Instead I would like to look up annotation usage at development time within my Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Have you looked into writing an Eclipse Plugin?  http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

Answer (score 11):

You can search for references in Eclipse. Click the annotation name, then right-click, select "References" and pick a scope for your search.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. There are problems with this approach, though: ... it may list false-positive results, e.g. classes that work with the annotation name reflectively (... AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Bean.class) != null; )... Additionally, this approach is limited to source code in my workspace. It doesn't check usage of an annotation inside libraries or my Maven repository. Any ideas here?

Comment: I agree that the false positives are ugly, but they are hard - if not impossible - to avoid because this search runs on a "semantic" level. About libs and/or Maven repos: I used to believe that Eclipse would search those as well, need to verify this on my work machine next week ;)

Comment: Cool! I'm curiously waiting for your results :)

Comment: @Abdull: There is a solution for the "false positive" problem. In the Eclipse search dialog there is  "Limit to" option. This can be set to "Match Locations" `->` "Annotations". That seems to limit the search results to only the use of the type as an annotation.

Answer (score 4):

You can Control-click on the annotation which will open the annotation definition class and then right-click and choose `References` -> `Workspace`.

EDIT:
I just checked it, and it is enough to right-click on the mentioned annotation and choosing `References` -> `Workspace` without even going into its definition.

Answer (score 2):

In [STS](https://spring.io/tools), there is an option in search:

[image: STS Pointcut Matches]

in which you can specify for example: `@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Service)` which will find all the classes marked with `@Service`