# How can i get all @Test annotated method names along with class names of entire project using java

Tags: java, junit, annotations

My code to get `@Test` annotated method names for a single class using Java:

```
public class AccountsTest
{

    @Test(dataProvider = "abc")
    public void login() {

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "bbc")
    public void logout() {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Annotation[] annotations = AccountsTest.class.getAnnotations(Test.class);
        Method[] methods = AccountsTest.class.getMethods();
        for(Method method:methods) {
            method.isAnnotationPresent(Test.class);
            System.out.println(method.getName());
        }
    }    
}
```

So How can I get all `@Test` annotated method names along with class names of entire project using Java?

Comment: It sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package?rq=1 answers this question.

Comment: Beware of that question's accepted answer.  It has two major mistakes:  It assumes all classes are in files (as opposed to jar entries), and it assumes URL.getFile() returns a path which can be safely passed to the java.io.File constructor.

Comment: thank you for given link.thats i want

Comment: is above link work for both application jar(war) and source project?