# Alternative supporting jakarta to `org.reflections:reflections` for finding annotated Methods

Tags: spring-boot, reflections, jakarta-migration

I am currently migrating to spring-boot 3. We use "org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2" in order to get all the classes in a package that contain a specific annotation (eg. `RequestMapping`.

```
  def requestMappingAnnotatedMethods() {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
        new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(rootPackage))
            .setScanners(new SubTypesScanner(), new MethodAnnotationsScanner()))
    return reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(RequestMapping)
  }
```

Unfortunately the reflections lib is not maintained anymore and currently results in an Exception, as it is expecting javax instead of jakarta.

Any idea, what alternative we can use or how we can achieve the same behaviour without the lib?

copy/paste of the needed classes is of course possible, but I was hoping to get a better way of dong our task :)

Comment: what about approved answer to this question [how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package), have you tried it yet ? it is a pure java code

Comment: @AndreiLisa many thanks, could you maybe post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered? :)

Comment: Hey, yep of course, I will do it )

Comment: i did it, also i dont want to copy paste the code I just set the reference to `Q/A` and some reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments solution can be approved answer(do it with `ClassLoader`) of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862106/how-to-find-annotated-methods-in-a-given-package), because [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) is currently NOT under active development or maintenance and last released is `org.reflections:reflections:0.10.2 (Oct 2021)`.

P.S. Also you have to `upvote` above linked solution.